# Is there a performance penalty lowering the sdk version

Tags: android, sdk

I have a published android app where the minSdk version is set to 8.
Since then I have realized that there really is nothing preventing me from lowering this requirement down to 3.

Is there a perfomance hit or anything else that should prevent me from doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a performance issue, lowering the minimum version will only means that devices running those versions will be able to run your app.

I wouldn't worry too much about reducing it from 8 to 3, though, because 8 is Android 2.2 and above, and that already covers 95% of the market as of today.

You can see a breakdown of the versions being used here: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: There might be some performance impacts, but impossible to say without empirical testing.  Many libraries and methods have been optimised and in some cases, completely re-written in later versions.  For example, some of the layout groups have much better performance in later releases but if your app does not use heavy UIs, you might not notice.

Comment: Wouldn't later versions of android use their implementation of the API? Or are you saying that all versions would suffer?